# Speeding up Euclidean Distance in python

Tags: numpy, python-3.6, knn

I am using a 32-core machine with 260GB RAM to do the following operation:

```
# features is a numpy array of shape (2932480, 4096)

# query is a (4096,) - dimensional descriptor


ans = np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(features - query, axis=1))[:100]
```

The total time to compute the euclidean norm is around 61 seconds, what are some ways I can parallelize the whole computations?

Comment: This looks interesting.  https://roman-kh.github.io/numpy-multicore/

Comment: Use : `cKDTree(features).query(query, k=100)[1]`.